# Slick - Making the portrait images the same height as the other ones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slick.js

I'm using slick in my rails app, but I encounter a problem that I can't fix. 
I want my images to have the same height, for that I used `adaptiveHeight: false`, but this is still happening:
[image]

I want the images that are in portrait mode to be the same height as the other ones, without me fixing the height statically. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

my html:

```
<div class="slider-for">
  <% @vehicle.images.each do |img| %>
    <%= image_tag img %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<div class="slider-nav">
  <% @vehicle.images.each do |img| %>
    <%= image_tag img %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

my javascript:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
    // autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 2000,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: true,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    adaptiveHeight: false,
    responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 550,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        centerPadding: '60px',
      }
    }]
  });
```

Thank you in advance!